# what is proper installed python directory structure on OSx?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-install

Hi I have python installed at multiple locations and I want to get rid of multiple location , just having one location would be nice, the problem is sometimes install modules with pip and sometimes with easy_install and I end up these modules getting installed to different site packages folder.

which tool is responsible for packages getting installed to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/`

a while back I installed exifread and after few months back I am running application that has dependence  on exifread was not able to find it, and pip install exifread was already saying exifread is installed, so I ran easy_install which added its path to

```
Adding ExifRead 1.4.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing EXIF.py script to /usr/local/bin
```

now I also had PyQt4 but somehow now its having trouble locating PyQt4.

It would be great if someone can really tell me how and where the python install of packages are supposed to go and how can we control each install no matter what tool we use to install.